# Twig - JavaScript booleans

Tags: javascript, php, types, twig

Is there a twig function that will allow me to convert a variable that contains a PHP boolean value into a literal JavaScript boolean?

At the moment my value of "true" from PHP is converted to a '1' in my twig template.
I've tried a few of the escape functions but nothing is working so far.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<script>
  // You can use it in literal code like this:
  var myBool = {{ mySuppliedValue ? 'true' : 'false' }};

  // Or in clientside string constants like this:
  console.log('The value is {{ mySuppliedValue ? 'true' : 'false' }}');
</script>
```

[See the docs](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators).

Comment: Second Twig call should be `myBool` since you've already retrieved it.

Comment: @DissidentRage my intent is to show some sample usage. In the second case I cannot use `{{ myBool }}` as you suggest - that variable exists in JS at that point, not in Twig.

Comment: Yeah, just use `console.log('The value is ' + myBool);`

Comment: That would kinda defeat the point of giving multiple examples on how to integrate it from Twig's end...

Answer (score 7):

You can use json:

```
<script>
  var myBool = {{ mySuppliedValue | json_encode }};
</script>
```